# How to carry Request Objects via a JSP without resorting to the Session?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Suppose I have two methods, `display()` and `submit()`, that show and submit my form, respectively. In between there is a JSP presented by `display()`, which I will save.

I want to set a Request Attribute to an object that will be carried forward and available to me on Submit. It is a complex object. On Submit I am losing this Req Attr. Do I need to use the Session (which is undesirable) to carry forward this piece of data?

My understanding is we should avoid dealing with the Session as much as possible, it's unreliable and risky.

```
public ModelAndView display(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

      MyComplexObj myComplexObj = getMyComplexObj();
     // Set Req Attr to a complex object
      request.setAttribute("myComplexObj", myComplexObj);
     // Return ModelAndView
     return new ModelAndView("form.jsp", "model", new Model());
}

public ModelAndView submit (HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("model") Model model) {
     request.getAttribute("myComplexObj"); // NULL - did not get carried forward
}
```

JSP: contains no references/variables.

Note: I can't use a Hidden Field in the JSP to carry forward this data, it's not a String but rather a Java object.

Comment: There aren't that many solutions. 1. user the session; 2. use hidden fields (you can have several ones; 3. store the data in the database or in some in-memory cache, or in the session, identified by an ID, and pass that ID as a hidden field; 4. Change the architecture and use JavaScript and AJAX to store state in the browser and pass it to the server as JSON. You could also pass a whole JSON object in a hidden field, BTW.

Comment: JB Nizet, use multiple Hidden Fields to record the complex object? Because a Hidden Field can't carry the object as a whole. But this would be very complicated.

Comment: It wouldn't be really more complicated than using a single hidden field. You would just do the same thing several times. And yes, you could store the whole object as JSON in a hidden field. But that said, given your example, I really don't understand why you're not creating this object in the submit method rather than the display method.

Comment: thanks. will think about doing it in the Submit

Answer (score 0):

Use spring form data binding technique to carry request object back to submit(). and don't use session to store attribute because why you waste extra memory with session whether it is easily achievable by spring form data binding.

But there is also an interesting and better solution.That is to use flash-attribute/Redirect-attribute :)

Comment: you may use @sessionattribute. But be careful to use this. It's your wish now what you will use.because there are many solutions